# Write command stdout to console and file (live) -- Python 3.5 + subprocess.run()

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, python-3.5

**Platform**: Python 3.5 on rhel6 (64-bit)

**Scenario**: Execute a Bash command which runs a job. This job returns several lines of output to stdout, every few seconds.

**Command**: `./run_job --name 'myjob' --config_file ./myconfig.conf`

**Goal**: Using Python's `subprocess.run()`, I am trying to run the above command and capture the stdout of the process, print it to the console and also save it to a file. I need the stdout to be printed as it becomes available (live).

**What I've Tried**: I have searched extensively for this, and every solution I found was using `subprocess.Popen()`. [This method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359) somewhat worked, but implementing it resulted in breaking the return logic I currently have. Reading through the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), the `subprocess.run()` method is the recommended way as of Python 3.5, so that's why I am going this route.

**My Setup**: So far, I have one common file with the logging and running the shell command below.

```
def setup_logging(log_lvl="INFO"):
    script_name = path.splitext(path.basename(__file__))[0]
    log_path = environ["HOME"] + "/logs/" + script_name + ".log"

    logging.basicConfig(
        level=getattr(logging, log_lvl.upper()),
        format="%(asctime)s: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
        handlers=[
            logging.FileHandler(filename=log_path, mode="w", encoding="utf-8"),
            logging.StreamHandler()
        ]
    )

def run_shell(cmd_str, print_stdout=True, fail_msg=""):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    result = run(cmd_str, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)

    cmd_stdout = result.stdout.strip()
    cmd_code = result.returncode
    if print_stdout and cmd_stdout != "":
        logger.info("[OUT] " + cmd_stdout)
    if cmd_code != 0 and fail_msg != "":
        logger.error(fail_msg)
        exit(cmd_code)
    return cmd_code, cmd_stdout
```

So I would use the following code to run my script:

`run_shell("./run_job --name 'myjob' --config_file ./myconfig.conf", fail_msg="Job failed.")`

This partially works, but the full stdout is printed only when the process has completed. So the terminal will hang until that happens. I need to print the stdout line by line, in a live manner, so that it can be written by the logger.

*Is there any way to do this without overhauling my existing code? Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: I recently worked with another SO user to interact with another subprocess: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60680949/7915759  The example can be applied in this scenario. You can read back stdout from the python script.

Comment: In that example, the thread could be modified to write every line it captures to a file, or you can do that in the main loop. Or just make the main loop the same algo as the thread and get rid of the thread and queue.

Comment: With `subprocess.run()`, I believe you have to wait until it completes and get its output all at once. With the solution I linked, you can capture the output as it comes in.  So what you describe as your live capture requirements won't be achievable with `run()`.

Comment: @Todd: Thanks for the link! I will take a look. I also had a feeling that it was not achievable with ```subprocess.run()```. If I can get it to work with what you provided, I will post back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for some time using threads and polling, I couldn't quite get it to work. However, from that same thread linked by **Todd**, I found another way to achieve what I need by using `Popen`:

```
def run_shell(cmd_str, print_stdout=True, fail_msg=""):
    """Run a Linux shell command and return the result code."""

    p = Popen(cmd_str,
              shell=True,
              stderr=STDOUT,
              stdout=PIPE,
              bufsize=1,
              universal_newlines=True)

    logger = logging.getLogger()

    output_lines = list()
    while True:
        output = p.stdout.readline().strip()
        if len(output) == 0 and p.poll() is not None:
            break
        output_lines.append(output)
        if print_stdout:
            logger.info("[cmd] " + output)

    cmd_code = p.returncode
    cmd_stdout = "\n".join(output_lines)
    if cmd_code != 0 and fail_msg != "":
        logger.error(fail_msg)
        exit(-1)

    return cmd_code, cmd_stdout
```

Comment: What are your dependencies? Did you import things in unusual ways? For example it should have been subprocess.Popen. Also afterwards it says STDOUT is not defined.